# C program emulating a scheduler

Tags: c, linux, exec, fork

I am learning C and trying to execute the following program.

In the past, I have used fork() and exec(), but for rather simple applications.

However, the program should do the following: 
    1. Program must use Fork() and Exec() 
    2. Must call several programs, one at a time 
    3. Must kill previous program, only one program running at a time 
    4. Program must run until `ctrl-c` is executed

Previous example `fork()` & `exec()` code. How can I modify the below code to implement the above steps?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    void runit(void);
    int pid;    /* process ID */

    switch (pid = fork())
    {
        case 0:     /* a fork returns 0 to the child */
            runit();
            break;

        default:    /* a fork returns a pid to the parent */
            sleep(5);   /* sleep for 5 seconds */
            printf("I'm still here!\n");
            break;

        case -1:    /* something went wrong */
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
    }
    exit(0);
}

void runit(void)
{
    printf("About to run ls\n");
    execlp("ls", "ls", "-af", "/", (char*)0);
    perror("execlp");   /* if we get here, execlp failed */
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: We're not here to do the work for you. Please read the man pages for each of the functions, think about how they apply to your assignment requirements and give it a red hot go. Come back with more specific questions if you still have difficulty.

Comment: @AlanAu I am not asking you to work for me. I just need a little head-start from my previous code.

Comment: Well then be more specific with your question. You have essentially just dumped the assignment question without much effort. It's your job to ask a specific question not ours to guess exactly what it is you need help with.

Comment: I want to know, that would i be calling several program in between the forkexec and then kiling each after forkexec. How can I keep the program running until `ctrl-c`

Answer (score 1):

Read up on signals.  You are going to want to send a signal to kill the old child process when you initiate the new one from the parent.  Your program will get a signal from the operating system when someone types ctrl+c.  You may also need to catch the signal you get from the O/S and do some cleanup (e.g. kill the old child process).

See, e.g., http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal

Also, obviously, you need to rewrite your program so it never exits unless it gets that signal.